# What method declaration accepts bounded and unbounded multi-level Generics?

Tags: java, bounded-wildcard

Given:

```
public class Testcase {

    public static <E> List<List<E>> transform(List<List<E>> list) {
        return list;
    }

    public static <E> List<List<? extends E>> transform2(List<List<? extends E>> list) {
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> known = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<? extends Number>> unknown = new ArrayList<>();

        transform(known);    // works
        transform(unknown);  // fails

        transform2(known);   // fails
        transform2(unknown); // works
    }
}
```

The compiler accepts `transform(known)` but complains:

```
cannot infer type-variable(s) E
    (argument mismatch; List<List<? extends Number>> cannot be converted to List<List<E>>)
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>transform(List<List<E>>)
```

for `transform(unknown)`. I get the opposite problem for `transform2()`. I've consulted [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/14731) and I believe that `transform()` is the correct method declaration but I can't for the life of my figure out how to get a single method to handle both cases.

Note that this problem only occurs for multi-level Generics. `List<? extends Number>` works just fine. The problem is not specific to Lists. You'll get it for `Future<Task<X>>` and so on.

**What method declaration will handle both bounded and unbounded Generics? And if it's not possible, why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most specific type for which this works seems to be `? extends List<? extends ?>`:

```
class Testcase {

    public <E> List<List<E>> transform(List<List<E>> list) {
        return list;
    }

    public <E> List<List<? extends E>> transform2(List<List<? extends E>> list) {
        return list;
    }

    public <E> List<? extends List<? extends E>> transform3(List<? extends List<? extends E>> list) {
        return list;
    }    

    public void test(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> known = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<? extends Number>> unknown = new ArrayList<>();

        transform(known);    // works
        // transform(unknown);  // fails

        // transform2(known);   // fails
        transform2(unknown); // works

        transform3(known);
        transform3(unknown);
    }
}
```

Here is an explanation why this makes sense.

A `List<? extends Number>` is clearly not a `List<E>` for any `E`, because it doesn't have to be able to insert instances of the most general `E`, thus the first definition fails.

A `List<Integer>` conforms to `List<? extends Number>`, but this does not help, because these types are still unequal, therefore types `List<List<Integer>>` and `List<List<? extends Number>>` are completely unrelated. Therefore, the second definition also fails.

What you want instead is the use-site least upper bound of `List<List<Integer>>` and `List<List<? extends Number>>`. You can obtain it using the following rule: the use-site-LUB of `List<A>` and `List<B>` is:

```
USLUB(List<A>, List<B>) = List<? extends USLUB(A, B)>
```

Now, step by step:

1. For `A = Integer` and `B = ? extends Number`, the least upper bound is `? extends Number`, because `Integer` conforms to `? extends Number`.
2. For `List<Integer>` and `List<? extends Number>` the least upper bound becomes `? extends List<? extends Number>`
3. Thus the final result is `List<? extends List<? extends Number>>`.

Hurray for use-site variance ;)

Comment: Ouch. My brain hurts. Any idea what why this works while the originals fail?

Comment: @Gili Yeah, that indeed hurts... But I've added a somewhat detailed explanation how to derive this funny type, I hope that it hurts a little less once you see the simple rule behind it ;)

Comment: I don't understand one thing about your explanation. Why is `? extends List<? extends Number>` considered an upper-bound of `List<Integer>`? I understand why `? extends List<Integer>` would act as an upper-bound but not the former.

Comment: @Gili `Integer` conforms to `? extends Number`. Therefore, `List<Integer>` is a special case of `List<? extends Number>`. In particular, `List<Integer>` conforms to `? extends List<? extends Number>`. The last statement is just a weakening of the stronger preceeding statement.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the step-by-step explanation.